# custom add note meta box with add button in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, html

I'm making a custom note meta box for plugin, and I have a note box input and one 'add' button in the box with. The button saves the text but does not move the text to the notepad but instead stays in the Box but saved, I'd like the text when saved to move to the note pad

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```php
    else {
            print '<hr />';
        }
        print '<div id="ppn_add_post_note" style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0;">';
        print '<label for="ppn_post_note">' . __('Add note:', 'peters_post_notes') . '</label><br />';
        print '<textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="ppn_post_note" id="ppn_post_note" style="width: 99%">
'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ppn_post_note', true).'
</textarea><br /><br />';
        print '<label><input type="checkbox" name="ppn_private" /> ' . __('Private note', 'peters_post_notes') . "</label>\n";
        print '</div>
<div style="text-align: right">
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="save_note">value="Add" tabindex="5" accesskey="p">

</div>

';
    }
```

Functions.php

```
            jQuery(document).on('click', '#save_note', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var note =  $('#ppn_post_note').val();

                var post_id = $('input[name="post_ID"]').val();
                var data = {
                    'post_id': post_id,
                    'note_movie': note,
                    'action': 'rt_note_save',
                }
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(resp){
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rt_movie_serial_save', 'rt_movie_serial_save');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_rt_movie_serial_save', 'rt_movie_serial_save' );
function rt_movie_serial_save(){
    if (isset($_POST['key'])) {
        $key = $_POST['key'];
        $bk_name = $_POST['bk_name'];
        update_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'serial-'.$key, $bk_name );
    }
    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rt_note_save', 'rt_note_save');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_rt_note_save', 'rt_note_save' );
function rt_note_save(){
    if (isset($_POST['note_movie'])) {
        $key = $_POST['note_movie'];
        $bk_name = $_POST['note_movie'];
        update_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'ppn_post_note', $bk_name );
    }
    die();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You'd have to do this with javascript, though there are already plugins for adding internal comments/notes to posts. Note that what you're describing is specific to the classic editor, which is very important information. I'd also suggest changing your code editor to one that includes basic features such as syntax highlighting and auto-complete. You should also share your code as code, not screenshots, otherwise anybody trying to help you has to transcribe the text out of the image before they can modify it which is a lot of work

Comment: ok cool thank you            .

Comment: hey Tom I added this code - <input name="publish" type="submit" id="publish" class="publish-button" value="Add" tabindex="5" accesskey="p"> - it adds a button but it updates the whole post I just want the note meta box updated please